# Transformar vídeo em objeto Blob?

Tags: php, java, jquery, ajax

Achei esse código em um tutorial que para transformar os vídeos em objetos e serem tratado como se fosse uma `url` `blob`, com o primeiro vídeo com vem na página a função funciona perfeitamente, porém quando chamo outro vídeo através do `Ajax` o mesmo ***não reproduz***, o único intuito desse código é ajudar a proteger o caminho original dos vídeos para evitar acesso direto, o que pode estar errado?

```
function mascara()
{
    var ms = new MediaSource();

    var video = document.querySelector('source');
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(ms);

    ms.addEventListener('sourceopen', function(e) {

      var sourceBuffer = ms.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"');
      sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(oneVideoWebMChunk);

    }, false);
};
```

Comment: minha dica nao use videos no banco de dados , coloca em uma pasta q ninguem tem acesso e faz um arquivo dar um include nele, mno db enquanto o video nao termina d ser carregado ele da um lock table outras pessoas nao vao conseguir acessar ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Os vídeos já estão em pastas, o que é recebido por Ajax é só o caminho esse novo vídeo que o usuário clicou, havendo retorno no sucesso eu chamo essa função pra mascarar o url do vídeo, porém o mesmo não reproduz :/